# Best way to map a parent-child list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Using C# here. I have a legacy class Person that contains 3 properties:

> 1. Id (guid)
> 2. Name
> 3. Parent Id (guid)

in SQL, it is stored in two tables:

> 1. Table Person: contains Id and Name
> 2. Table Relationship: contains PersonId, ParentId

Given objects of Person, for example (not showing guid for simplicity):

> - parent1: Id = 1, Name = Bob, ParentId = empty
> - child1: Id = 2, Name = Scott, ParentId = 1
> - child11: Id = 3, Name = Scott jr, ParentId = 2
> - child12: Id = 4, Name = John, ParentId = 2
> - parent2: Id = 5, Name = James, ParentId = empty
> - child21: Id = 6, Name = James jr, ParentId = 5

I'd like to build `List<NewPerson>`
where `NewPerson` is a class that contains:

> - Id
> - Name
> - Children as `List<NewPerson>`

To display them in tree form:

> - Bob
> - --- Scott
> - -------- Scott Jr
> - -------- John
> - James
> - --- James Jr

Is there an efficient way to map that old flat `List<Person>` into an hierarchical (generational) `List<NewPerson>`?

Comment: The traditional way to do this in a database is to have a third (nullable) column in the person table named ParentId.  With that, you don't need the "Relationship" table.  Then to get the whole hierarchy, you do a "self-join" (or a "recursive self-join") (good keywords for a search).  What ORM are you using (EF, Linq2Sql, Dapper, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

I write a Test for this issue, before that attention which Where did data come from? Database? or they are in memory??

I write both state of those.

1. Code for data that come from Database:

   ```
       listPerson.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId).Select(x => new TreePerson()
       {
           Id = x.First(c=>c.ParentdId == x.Key).Id,
           Name = x.First(c => c.ParentId == x.Key).Name,
           Children = x.Where(c => c.ParentdId == x.Key).GroupBy(c => c.Id).Select(c 
               => new Person()
           {
               Id = c.Key,
               Name = c.First(z => z.Id == c.Key).Name,
               SubLevelPerson = c.FirstOrDefault(v=>v.ParentdId == c.Key)
           }).ToList()
       });
   ```
2. Code for data that is in memory:

   ```
       listPerson.Where(x => x.ParentdId == null).Select(x => new TreePerson()
       {
           Id = x.Id,
           Name = x.Name,
           Children = listPerson.Where(c => c.ParentdId == x.Id).GroupBy(c => c.Id).Select(c => new Person()
           {
               Id = c.Key,
               Name = c.First(z => z.Id == c.Key).Name,
               SubLevelPerson = c.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ParentdId == c.Key)
           }).ToList()
       });
   ```

Attention that your classes should like this classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentdId { get; set; }
    public Person SubLevelPerson { get; set; }
}

public class TreePerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Those code are for Multi level data.

GoodLuck.